# Galactic rotation speeds - questions from a non-astronomer

Tags: galaxy, galactic-dynamics

1. Are there any observations that more distant galaxies appear to rotate more slowly than closer galaxies?
2. What methods are used to measure the rotational speed of galaxies? (both orbital speed profiles and/or bulk average rotation speed)
3. What is the current limit for how far away a galaxy can be to make such measurements?

I greatly appreciate any answer or links to info on this topic.  I am not an astronomer by profession or education, just deeply fascinated with cosmology.

Comment: Regarding #1, that is very specific - suggesting you have a hypothesis. Please see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/156611/the-doppler-shift-and-the-apparent-speed-of-galactic-rotation-with-distance/301560#301560

Comment: Thank you.  Your description in the link answers question #2 very well. Any idea about the greatest distance over which these types of measurements have been made?  My guess is that no discernible correlation between rotation speed and distance has been detected, since it would probably be widely discussed, but has it been ruled out?  I imagine estimating inclination is inexact, making such measurements quite fuzzy.